# facebook post link (via <application name>)

Tags: facebook, api, post

When we post on facebook by using an APP ID , the application name comes under the post which links to the application page.I need to link it to my site. I found this : postplanner.com/schedule-facebook-posts-branded-app . its a paid service . can i do it myself?

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you please elaborate on what you want to do, and also it would help a lot if you could add some code which is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app has a canvas implementation (apps.facebook.com/yourapp) that's where the link will go, if you don't, it'll go to your website

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be useful :

1. First Create your Facebook Application
2. Enter the Redirect Uri if any in the facebook app.
3. Include this url where ever you want to post it via your app name in the newsfeed
   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id="APP_ID"&redirect_uri="Redirect URI"

Or Check out this link for further clarification

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/customize-facebook-status/